# Wikipedia Search: input txt line into <form> php html

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I need to input the line in a .txt file into the value of the search variable in a form.
Here's mi html code:

```
    <form action="http://www.wikipedia.org/search-redirect.php" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="search" value=""/>  
    <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en" />
    <input type="image" src="/img/masinfo.png" width="218" height="40" alt="mas informacion"  name="go" value="Mas informacion del artista" />
    </form>
```

On the other hand i have this php code to extrat the line from the .txt file:

```
<?php
$file = "file.txt";
$f = fopen($file, "r");
while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
  $line = preg_replace("/^example.*/", "example", $line);
  $line = preg_replace("/0[0-9]{2}/", "", $line);
 print $line;

}
?>
```

Is there a way to input this line into the search value of the form?

Edit: the line is something like

```
 124 hello world - universe
```

Comment: echo your $line and post here. So that we can know what exactly this $line ocntains.

Comment: So you want 124 hello world - universe as your search string? Am I right?

Comment: not specifically. i posted it as an example of the type of text its inside the txt file. the thing is the file is continually updating itself thats why i want to automatically input the text inside the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
$file = "file.txt"; 
$f = fopen($file, "r"); 
while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) { 
  $line = preg_replace("/^example.*/", "example", $line); 
  $line = preg_replace("/0[0-9]{2}/", "", $line); 
} 
?> 

<form action="http://www.wikipedia.org/search-redirect.php" method="get" target="_blank"> 
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="<?php echo $line; ?>"/>   
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="en" /> 
<input type="image" src="/img/masinfo.png" width="218" height="40" alt="mas informacion"  name="go" value="Mas informacion del artista" /> 
</form>
```

If your `$line` variable will contain characters like `"` you should replace it before echoing it

Comment: $line will be overlaped by new string every time inside the loop.

Comment: where should i put the php lines of code? inside the body?
its giving a php error

Comment: at the head? inside the script? sory for the ignorance

Comment: this isn't working.. it makes a search with the following search string: `<?php echo $line; ?>`

Comment: the entire code I wrote above should be placed in the same file having the `.php` extension. A PHP file can contain also PHP scripts and HTML code